# To read Double values

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to read double values stored in a text file and store those values in an array.The input file has one value in each line. Following is my code.

```
File file=new File("val.txt");
 List<Double> value = new ArrayList<Double>();
     Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
     while(input.hasNext()){
       value.add(scanner.nextDouble());}
```

But i get Nosuchelement exception. What is wrong the code?. How to read double values from the file and store it?

Comment: You should check for `input.hasNextDouble()`, `hasNext` means that there is something to read, but you don't know if it's a double or not

Comment: @BackSlash : tried hasNextDouble(), still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you tell me which line is causing the error? Post the stacktrace too

Comment: @BackSlash : getting the following:Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
 at test.test.main(test.java:24)

Comment: Which line is line 24 in test.java?

Comment: @BackSlash : value.add(scanner.nextDouble())

Comment: Does the file exists and you have the right to read it?

Comment: @HectorLector If the file didn't exist, the program would have fired a `FileNotFoundException`, if the program didn't have permissions to read it, it would have fired a `Permission denied` exception, so it shouold exist and the program has permissions to read it

Comment: @HectorLector : yes, it exists. Tried the command System.out.println( file.exists()); and got true for that .

Comment: @Keerthana The error you're getting is weird, I don't know how to help

Comment: @BackSlash : oh !! okay.. Anyways thanks.. Is there any other way to read the values?

Comment: try file.canRead() and post the content of the file. What decimal seperator do you use?

Comment: @HectorLector : got true for that .. contents are 8.233 , 4.567 , 52.11 ,45.532 . Each line has only one value. (I just typed all the values in a single line here)

Comment: And there are no extra spaces, strange characters etc.? Which language settings are you using (in some countries ',' is the decimal seperator). Otherwise just try with only one value and see if it works.

Comment: @Keerthana Could you post the exact content of the file you're trying to read in your question?

Comment: @ZouZou :  8.233 , 4.567 , 52.11 ,45.532 (each in seperate line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are using 2 scanners. You're checking with one if it has a value and you're trying to add this value using another scanner.

Use only the `input` one.

So change it to:

```
File file=new File("val.txt");
List<Double> value = new ArrayList<Double>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
while(input.hasNextDouble()){
   value.add(input.nextDouble());
}
```

Note that the `Scanner` use your default locale (if you don't specify one). So if this locale separates decimals by a `,` you'll add nothing to your `List`. So make sure you use one that separates decimals by a dot.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file).useLocale(Locale.UK);
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked.. I have another doubt..can I convert the list to an array using double names[]=value.toArray(new double[value.size()]) ?

Comment: @Keerthana No you can't because `toArray(T [])` requires a generic array as parameter. So it cannot work with primitive. However you can use the wrapper class `Double`: `Double names[]=value.toArray(new Double[value.size()]);`